# Hide toolbar in Evince, Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: 13.10, updates, menu, evince

I find that the View menu has disappeared in the newest version of Evince. Is there still a way to hide the toolbar? I would like to do this in order to share a presentation using a Google Hangout-on-Air. So far, the toolbar shows up at the top. Thanks.

Comment: Which version of evince are you using?

Comment: It is version 3.10.0.

Answer (score 3):

The toolbar in evince is apparently buggy, according to bug reports, and it is not possible to hide it, ever, as it remembers per-file settings, which override/ignore the toolbar visibility setting adjusted via e.g. dconf-editor.

It is a shame that evince, which works so well, has this glitch in the UI. The visibility toolbar should be adjusted from a "View" menu. Please bring that view menu back.