# How do I hide the Toolbar in Evince Full Screen Mode?

Tags: 14.04, pdf, evince

Let me preface this by saying I'm new to Linux, but I'm willing to try anything you wizards can conjure up (preferably a keyboard shortcut though)!

When I use Evince 3.10.3 in full screen mode I'm greeted with this nice-looking, but semi-annoying toolbar that takes up some of my screen real estate at the top...:

[image: That Beautiful Toolbar That's Getting in My Way...]

In the Evince documentation I see that the section on the Toolbar says to *Show, hide, or edit the toolbar*; when I go to the page all I see is a layout of the corresponding functions of the toolbar, but no information is given as to how I can hide the toolbar:

[image: Okay, This Looks Good!]
[image: Wait, Where's The Tip & Trick?!]

How do I hide the toolbar in Evince version 3.10.3, or a version that includes this similar setup with the toolbar?

P.S. Sometimes the toolbar magically fades away. I just want a way to invoke this behavior on demand. Thanks!

Comment: have you tried F5 , which is presentation mode ? there's no toolbar there

Comment: I have tried F5, which does remove the toolbar, but unfortunately zooming is disabled in presentation mode as well. I want to be able to zoom to page-width.

Comment: there is [similar post](http://askubuntu.com/questions/430822/hide-toolbar-in-evince-ubuntu-13-10) asked in earlier release as well, except without any workaround.

Comment: The toolbar 'magically fades away' when the mouse is not near it. As you are using Gnome you can use the Pixel Saver or Maximus two extensions to hide the titlebars of most apps, like Chrome does (sort of). Also, what theme are you using :)

Comment: Atril Document viewer is essentially Eveince withouth gnome and pressing "T" the toolbar goes away

Answer (score 5):

The short answer is, you can't.

Evince 3.4.0 (on 12.04) had the option to hide the toolbar from the menu *View > Toolbar* then select *Fullscreen* from the menu or via <kbd>F11</kbd> key will hide the toolbar in fullscreen mode.

Apparently, this feature has been removed from newer version of Evince and it has been reported as [bug on launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/evince/+bug/1409291) and in [mailing list](https://mail.gnome.org/archives/evince-list/2014-October/msg00007.html) as well.

Perhaps this might be fixed with newer version, but who knows.

Immediate workarounds would be either:

- using window manager as suggested by @zarnaik
- use other PDF viewer such as [MuPDF](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/mupdf/), etc.

I have used MuPDF on Xubuntu 14.04, and it seems to achieve what you want: no toolbar and able to zoom to any width, while viewing in fullscreen.

Answer (score 3):

I came across the exact same problem you did. I have **not been able to sucessfully hide the toolbar**, though I have come up with a way to **emulate the behaviour**.

I simply maximise the evince window. Then using keyboard shortcuts <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd> to open up the window context menu.

[image: resize]

Follow this by <kbd>z</kbd> to select resiz̲e in the menu (in English, may differ depending on language used). Once in resize-mode you should be able to use the arrow key <kbd>Up</kbd> to enlarge the window. 
You simply elongate it until both menu and toolbar are "outside" of the screen.

Alternatively, you simply drag down the window a little and lengthen it as needed. then drag it back up.

It may be possible that evince appears under any dock or task bar you have running, this can be fixed by setting the window layer to `always on top`.

[image: always on top]

I am not familiar with the dock/task bar you use, so results may vary. Let me know if it works out for you. (I use openbox with tint2 dock)

Comment: Very nice work around

Answer (score 2):

Hiding the toolbar is not possible in evince either in Ubuntu 14.04 or 16.04, nor in upstream/vanilla evince (unmodified by Ubuntu), though if you're desperate, you can patch the source and recompile.

In vanilla evince, in full-screen mode, the toolbar autohides, which is somewhat helpful, if not entirely sufficient (semi-intelligent behaviour never does exactly what you desire, plus it would be very convenient to be able to hide the toolbar not in full-screen mode as well — arguably that is when the screen-space savings are particularly important).

Unfortunately, for evince as packaged in Ubuntu (14.04 and 16.04), even that is not possible. It seems that the (otherwise very useful) Ubuntu-specific patches returning a normal menu-bar and normal location of the toolbar, break the auto-hiding behaviour, exacerbating the problem.

## Bug reports

The relevant bugs (ubuntu-specific and upstream) are here:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/evince/+bug/1522527

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/evince/+bug/1409291

https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=714996

## Patches

Working patches were provided (by Reinis Danne) in the GNOME bug report, but they were not accepted. Direct links for [3.12](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/attachment.cgi?id=280526), [the contemporary master branch](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/attachment.cgi?id=280541) and [3.14](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/attachment.cgi?id=293927).

Luckily, these patches can still be manually applied (copy-pasting the code) to evince 3.18, as found in Ubuntu 16.04. Applying them directly with `patch` appears not to work, probably due to slight changes in the surrounding code.

To get the source:

```
apt-get source evince
cd evince-3.18.2/
```

If this doesn't work, uncomment the `deb-src` lines in `/etc/apt/sources.list`.

Apply the following patch (adapted from the ones provided by Reinis Danne, linked above and provided here for completeness):

```
--- a/shell/ev-application.c    2018-01-02 23:00:00.502095551 +0100
+++ b/shell/ev-application.c    2018-01-03 23:15:00.713553169 +0100
@@ -1059,9 +1059,24 @@
 }

 static void
+app_toggle_toolbar_cb (GSimpleAction *action,
+                       GVariant      *parameter,
+                       gpointer       user_data)
+{
+        EvApplication *application = user_data;
+        EvWindow      *window      = EV_WINDOW (gtk_application_get_active_window (GTK_APPLICATION (application)));
+        GActionMap    *action_map  = G_ACTION_MAP (window);
+        GAction       *gaction     = g_action_map_lookup_action (action_map, "toggle-toolbar");
+
+        g_action_activate (gaction, NULL);
+}
+
+
+static void
 ev_application_startup (GApplication *gapplication)
 {
         const GActionEntry app_menu_actions[] = {
+       { "toggle-toolbar", app_toggle_toolbar_cb, NULL, NULL, NULL },
        { "new",  app_new_cb, NULL, NULL, NULL },
                 { "help", app_help_cb, NULL, NULL, NULL },
                 { "about", app_about_cb, NULL, NULL, NULL }
@@ -1095,6 +1110,7 @@
           "win.caret-navigation",       "F7", NULL,
           "win.zoom-in",                "plus", "<Ctrl>plus", "KP_Add", "<Ctrl>KP_Add", "equal", "<Ctrl>equal", NULL,
           "win.zoom-out",               "minus", "<Ctrl>minus", "KP_Subtract", "<Ctrl>KP_Subtract", NULL,
+          "win.toggle-toolbar",         "<Ctrl>H", NULL,
           "win.show-side-pane",         "F9", NULL,
           "win.fullscreen",             "F11", NULL,
           "win.presentation",           "F5", NULL,
--- a/shell/ev-window.c 2018-01-02 23:00:00.502095551 +0100
+++ b/shell/ev-window.c 2018-01-02 23:14:36.995706943 +0100
@@ -4907,6 +4907,27 @@
 }

 static void
+ev_window_view_cmd_toggle_toolbar (GSimpleAction *action,
+                                   GVariant      *state,
+                                   gpointer       user_data)
+{
+        EvWindow        *ev_window = user_data;
+        EvWindowPrivate *priv      = ev_window->priv;
+
+        gboolean toolbar;
+        gboolean presentation;
+
+        presentation = EV_WINDOW_IS_PRESENTATION (ev_window);
+
+        toolbar = ((priv->chrome & EV_CHROME_TOOLBAR) != 0  ||
+                   (priv->chrome & EV_CHROME_RAISE_TOOLBAR) != 0) && !presentation;
+
+        update_chrome_flag (ev_window, EV_CHROME_TOOLBAR, !toolbar);
+
+        set_widget_visibility (priv->toolbar, !toolbar);
+}
+
+static void
 ev_window_view_cmd_toggle_sidebar (GSimpleAction *action,
                   GVariant      *state,
                   gpointer       user_data)
@@ -5697,6 +5718,7 @@
    { "continuous", NULL, NULL, "true", ev_window_cmd_continuous },
    { "dual-page", NULL, NULL, "false", ev_window_cmd_dual },
    { "dual-odd-left", NULL, NULL, "false", ev_window_cmd_dual_odd_pages_left },
+   { "toggle-toolbar", NULL, NULL, "true", ev_window_view_cmd_toggle_toolbar },
    { "show-side-pane", NULL, NULL, "false", ev_window_view_cmd_toggle_sidebar },
    { "inverted-colors", NULL, NULL, "false", ev_window_cmd_view_inverted_colors },
    { "fullscreen", NULL, NULL, "false", ev_window_cmd_view_fullscreen },
--- a/shell/evince-menus.ui 2018-01-02 23:00:00.502095551 +0100
+++ b/shell/evince-menus.ui 2018-01-03 23:16:02.969635772 +0100
@@ -21,6 +21,12 @@
   <menu id="appmenu">
     <section>
       <item>
+        <attribute name="label" translatable="yes">_Toggle toolbar</attribute>
+        <attribute name="action">app.toggle-toolbar</attribute>
+        <attribute name="accel">&lt;Primary&gt;H</attribute>
+      </item>
+    </section>    <section>
+      <item>
         <attribute name="label" translatable="yes">_New Window</attribute>
         <attribute name="action">app.new</attribute>
       </item>
@@ -41,6 +47,10 @@
   <menu id="view-menu">
     <section>
       <item>
+        <attribute name="label" translatable="yes">_Toolbar</attribute>
+   <attribute name="action">win.toggle-toolbar</attribute>
+      </item>
+      <item>
         <attribute name="label" translatable="yes">_Continuous</attribute>
         <attribute name="action">win.continuous</attribute>
       </item>
```

with `patch -p1 < name_of_patch_file.patch` or using `quilt` (and ideally read the patch before/after applying it — it's actually quite comprehensible, especially in context).

Finally, compile evince with the standard `./configure; make; sudo make install` to install the patched evince to `/usr/local/`. To install elsewhere, for example to avoid having to use `sudo`, use `./configure --prefix=/full/path/to/alternative/location/`.

The patched evince will have the option of hiding the toolbar with `Ctrl+h`. The menu-bar will *not* be hidden, which may or may not be what you want.

### Hiding the menu-bar

In addition to the above patch, you would need to add:

```
gtk_application_window_set_show_menubar (GTK_APPLICATION_WINDOW (ev_window), !toolbar);
```

to the end of the definition of `ev_window_view_cmd_toggle_toolbar` in `shell/ev-window.c` and change:

```
gtk_application_window_set_show_menubar (GTK_APPLICATION_WINDOW (window), !presentation);
```

to:

```
gtk_application_window_set_show_menubar (GTK_APPLICATION_WINDOW (window), !presentation && toolbar);
```

in the definition of `update_chrome_visibility`, also in `shell/ev-window.c`.

## Security

I'd also recommend adding a `/etc/apparmor.d/usr.local.bin.evince` apparmor profile based on `usr.bin.evince` and subscribing to the [Ubuntu security notices](https://usn.ubuntu.com/usn/), since you won't be receiving security fixes to your version of evince. Alternatively, you might consider using something like `apt-src`.

Comment: For ease of application, both full patches are here: https://gist.github.com/aplaice/5b2b75c410ee32ad57335466713b75e8

Comment: For later versions of Evince, it seems that Reinis Danne (the original author of the patch described in this answer) has a soft fork of Evince allowing toggling of toolbars [here](https://gitlab.gnome.org/Reinis/evince/-/tree/toggle_toolbar), but I haven't tested it yet.

Answer (score 2):

If you come here in 2023, I maintain patches for evince with the functionality of hiding the menu bar (toolbar) with a keyboard shortcut and many more. (https://github.com/fabian-thomas/evince-patches)

Answer (score 1):

I am using maximus without title bar everywhere.

I solved zoom issue with magnifier in accessibility option. 
Shortcut: <kbd>Alt</kbd>+Scroll

Answer (score 1):

The default Document Viewer application (evince) in Ubuntu has **true full screen mode**. From the Evince toolbar select *View* -> *Presentation*. In presentation mode there is no visually distracting toolbar or scrollbar on the screen. It looks like viewing an image in full screen mode, perfect for viewing the .pdf digital booklets that are sometimes bundled with albums that can be downloaded from iTunes or 7digital.

To exit from presentation mode press either the <kbd>Esc</kbd> key or <kbd>F11</kbd>.

Comment: But the problem is you can have full width in presentation mode. The characters look so small

Comment: Presentation mode looks nice for viewing the digital booklets that come with albums downloaded from iTunes or 7digital.

Answer (score 0):

With Evince in Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS in February 2023, I use

- **<kbd>F5</kbd>** to enter into full screen mode without a toolbar and
- **<kbd>Esc</kbd>** to exit from full screen mode into window mode.

If I remember correctly, these hotkeys have worked for several years in the Evince versions via apt (and the main repository) of Ubuntu Desktop and the Ubuntu community flavours.

Answer (score -1):

It's easy to get your thinking locked up to search for "a PDF reader" forgetting that you are most likely have a browser, and browsers like Chrome and Firefox have rather good PDF reading abilities(select cut,copy/past, bookmarking, scrolling continuously ... in contrast to MuPDF who is useful to just display a PDF as image and still broke it on scrolling) in addition to what you want that is a clear full screen without any distractions. As a bonus you can use browser features such as selecting/right click then search google for ... Try it.